# How do I control the order in which ApplicationListener beans gets called?

Tags: java, spring

When I have multiple beans that implements the `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` interface, how do I control that certain beans get called before other beans?

Does it make more sense for the dependency to be handled inside the bean itself?

Comment: I think the order in which you define them in your spring files is the Order in which they are instantiated, but not really sure...

Comment: Beans that implement this interface get called after they have been instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AbstractApplicationContext`, I could see the following snippet which takes care of registering `ApplicationListener` implemented beans.

```
Collection listeners = getBeansOfType(ApplicationListener.class, true, false).values();
for (Iterator it = listeners.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  addListener((ApplicationListener) it.next());
}
```

Here `getBeansOfType` found to be returning `Map` and hence ordering is **non-deterministic**. This is the way it works in case of `spring-2.0`.

Comment: I think it makes sense not to rely on ContextRefreshedEvents when there has to be some ordering in which event handlers perform their task. I'm going to try an alternate approach.

Comment: I used to think I need to perform the work after the bean as been initialized (like when the context gets refreshed). I now choose to do the work during the construction of the bean. This way I can define an explicit depends-on relationship in the xml file.

Comment: Note that this answer is out of date. It appears that `ApplicationListener` invocations are appropriately sorted via the `Ordered` interface as of Spring 3.0.0.M2 ([commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/60392d6e7416ea2e4c594c7f93b07bfa30e79501)). See @Sebastian's answer for an up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the Ordered interface to specify this ordering. See [this blogpost](http://www.scorgar.be/blog/java-equivalent-of-an-import-sql-using-applicationlistener/).